# Листинг каталога для node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

В разделе версий, на сайте Ноды, есть вот такой проводник [image: sample]

Простой, без стилей, лёгкий.
Мне нужно что то такое для моего проекта на express.

```
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

На данный момент, когда я хочу получить доступ ко всей папке в директории client, у меня выпадает ошибка Cannot GET, хотя ко всем файлам, если указать путь к ним, доступ есть.

Есть идеи, можно ли это реализовать через какой ни будь пакет, или нужно что то дописать в настройках экспресса ? Чтобы ненужно было создавать отдельный индексный файл, и писать пути к нужным файлам, а чтобы в место этого, был автоматический парсинг файлов и папок, допустим в директории client.

Comment: 1. https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=autoindex

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index

Comment: Спасибо, nginx для линукса, а вот пакет serve-index посмотрю.

Comment: 1. https://nginx.org/ru/docs/windows.html 2. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Answer (score 1):

[image: ansver]
Пакет serve-index работает вот с такими настройками

```
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'), serveIndex('client', {'icons': true}))
```

Спасибо Alexey Ten за совет.